# Comparing characters in R

Tags: r, compare

How does comparing characters work? All I've been able to determine is that they are not converted to ascii.

```
> 'b' > 11
[1] TRUE
> 'b' < 99999999
[1] FALSE
> 'b' > 'a'
[1] TRUE
> 'b' > 'B'
[1] FALSE
> 'A' > 'b'
[1] FALSE
```

What is the logic here?

Comment: Take a look at `?Comparison`. You will see "If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of precedence being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and raw. "

Comment: And also: "*Character strings can be compared with different marked encodings (see Encoding): they are translated to UTF-8 before comparison.*" You can get to the help page by searching `?">"`, `help(">")`, etc.